# How to connect to virtual network on linux

Tags: networking, arch-linux, virtualbox

I start most of my virtual machines using virtual box.

Most of the time I configure them with bridge networking. But this time I would like to set it up with nat network.

I added a virtual network on virtual box: 10.0.2.0/24 and launch the box. Now I would like to connect to it from my host system. But I do not know how to add the virtual interface and take my IP with the ip command (Arch Linux).

A similar interrogation is how can I set up the virtual machine network (still in virtual box) so that the box can only be contacted from my host system.

Comment: Virtuualbox has a host only networking option.

Comment: See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html and askl a more specific question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay found it.

You need to add a host only network in virtual box.

Then configure the VM to use the host-only network.

And finally take an address on this virtual network with the command ip:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.56.1/24 dev vboxnet
```